# Mounting subdir to a new NFS

Tags: nfs, mkdir, nfsv4

I have a directory that is mounted with NFS.

```
10.159.31.81:/var/lib/phone /var/lib/phone nfs hard,bg,intr,vers=3,noatime 0 0
```

I want to test my new NFS servers but I don't want to move everything over. For now I just want to add an entry so that I can have `/var/lib/phone/backups` mount to a new NFS server.  In `/etc/fstab` I have:

```
10.159.31.88:/var/lib/phone/backups /var/lib/phone/backups nfs hard,bg,intr,noatime 0 0
```

When I try to mount it I get an error of `mount.nfs: mounting 10.159.31.88:/var/lib/phone/backups failed, reason given by server: No such file or directory`

Which is understandable since on the local server the only directory that exits is `/var/lib/phone`. Is there any other option other than unmounting the NFS mount, creating the directory and then re-mounting both NFS shares?

EDIT: I am able to mount it under a different directory (e.g. /mnt/test) however I have an appilcaiton that is want to write specfically to that directory (`/var/lib/phone/backups`)

Comment: Have you tried manually mounting `10.159.31.88:/var/lib/phone/backups` to some other mount point, like `/mnt`?  What happened? … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: directory must exists localy before issuing `mount` command